# Apache Spark logging redirects WebSphere log output

Tags: logging, apache-spark, websphere, slf4j

For testing purposes I want to run Spark in local mode on a WebSphere Application Server. The problem is, as soon as a local spark context is initialized, it redirects *all* logging within the WebSphere server through the Spark logger.

What I mean by "redirect" is: All log lines, without exception and regardless which WebSphere component or application, are logged to SystemErr according to the WebSphere log. On each logged message you can then see another timestamp and the log level and logger name before the actual log message.

From other questions I figured out that both WebSphere and Spark use SLF4J internally. How can I prevent the SLF4J in Spark from redirecting all logging from other applications through itself?

I'm using WebSphere Application Server v8.5.5.6 and Apache Spark v1.4.1 CHD4 binary distribution.

Comment: Hi, are you using Liberty or classic WebSphere?

Comment: That would be the "classic" WebSphere, definitely not Liberty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach seems to have solved my logging problem:

1. Delete the `slf4j` folder under the `org` folder in the Spark jar file. (Any standard tool for modifying ZIP files will work here.)
2. Add the API and JDK14 jars for SLF4J as libraries to the web application, in addition to the modified Spark jar.

(To be honest, I didn't put much additional effort into trying to configure Spark's logging anymore and my approach may be a little blunt, but it works.)

The above steps successfully prevent Spark from taking over the WebSphere logging. Instead, all Spark-generated logs are handled by WebSphere as it should be.

Of course that will not work around other deficiencies, such as Spark only allowing a single SparkContext per JVM (and all applications on a WebSphere node run in a single JVM), so this kind of setup will continue to be for testing purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that slf4j with spark is configuring the root logger (e.g. the SLF4J bridge handler), which routes all JUL logger output to SLF4J, which is then logging to System.err.

Liberty needs and uses JUL (in addition to our own). Anything that messes with the root JUL log handler is going to mess with Liberty's logging (thank you JVM singletons). It looks like Apache Spark assumes/enforces use of log4j, and assumes it should route all JUL over log4j as well.

You would need to configure log4j to handle Liberty messages differently, or wrestle with Apache Spark (perhaps making some modifications there) to allow use of JUL (which then Liberty manages via server.xml configurations).

Or perhaps modify slf4j(logback.xml) configuration, per this post: 
[How to customize logging levels for Cassandra and Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471550/how-to-customize-logging-levels-for-cassandra-and-spark)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that tomorrow. I had hoped I could get it to work without much effort, so hopefully I can convince it to do what I want without having to compile it on my own.